# Why do I have to click a UIButton twice to get the menu to open?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

I have a UIButton with a UIMenu associated with it. When I run the app I have to click the button twice to see the menu. Only the first time. If I click the button again the menu opens up right away. Tried both in the simulator and on the actual device. Running Xcode 14.2 and Swift 5.

I tried marking the button with its role as primary. I tried marking the button with its state already selected. Not sure what else to try. Also, tried restarting Xcode just in case it was some bug in Xcode.

```
    @IBAction func oxygenButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let twolpm = UIAction(title: "2 LPM") { (action) in
            self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
            self.codeLog.append(CodeLog(event: (sender.titleLabel?.text)!, time: (self.dateFormatter.string(from: self.date)), note: "2LPM"))}
        let fourlpm = UIAction(title: "4 LPM") { (action) in
            self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
            self.codeLog.append(CodeLog(event: (sender.titleLabel?.text)!, time: (self.dateFormatter.string(from: self.date)), note: "4LPM"))}
        let sixlpm = UIAction(title: "6 LPM") { (action) in
            self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
            self.codeLog.append(CodeLog(event: (sender.titleLabel?.text)!, time: (self.dateFormatter.string(from: self.date)), note: "6LPM"))}
        let eightlpm = UIAction(title: "8 LPM") { (action) in
            self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
            self.codeLog.append(CodeLog(event: (sender.titleLabel?.text)!, time: (self.dateFormatter.string(from: self.date)), note: "8LPM"))}
        let tenlpm = UIAction(title: "10 LPM") { (action) in
            self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
            self.codeLog.append(CodeLog(event: (sender.titleLabel?.text)!, time: (self.dateFormatter.string(from: self.date)), note: "10LPM"))}
        let fifteenlpm = UIAction(title: "15 LPM") { (action) in
            self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
            self.codeLog.append(CodeLog(event: (sender.titleLabel?.text)!, time: (self.dateFormatter.string(from: self.date)), note: "15LPM"))}
        let oxygenmenu = UIMenu(title: "Oxygen Menu", options: .displayInline, children:
                                    [twolpm, fourlpm, sixlpm, eightlpm, tenlpm, fifteenlpm])
        sender.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        sender.menu = oxygenmenu
    }
```

Comment: When you have the same code repeated over and over with only the data changing, that’s a “code smell”, and suggests that you should be able to rewrite it by looping over an array of data. You should be able to have an array `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15]`, loop through that, and build your IBActions from that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the button's `menu` and `showsMenuAsPrimaryAction` properties before the button is ever tapped. So you probably want to do it in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method. Then (in your storyboard) you should remove the button's connection to the `oxygenButtonPressed` method, and remove the `oxygenButtonPressed` method entirely.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let date = ...
    let codeLog = ...
    @IBOutlet var oxygenButton: UIButton!   
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        
        let actions: [UIAction] = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15].map { lpm in
            let title = "\(lpm) LPM"
            return UIAction(title: title) { [weak self] _ in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.codeLog.append(CodeLog(
                    event: title,
                    time: dateFormatter.string(from: self.date),
                    note: "\(lpm)LPM"
                ))
            }
        }
        
        oxygenButton.menu = UIMenu(
            title: "Oxygen Menu",
            options: .displayInline,
            children: actions
        )
        oxygenButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> When I run the app I have to click the button twice to see the menu.

Yup. Because that's exactly what your code says should happen.

Think about it. Your action method runs when the button is tapped. Your action method adds the menu.

So the *first* time you tap the button, there was no menu, but the action method runs and adds it — and that's all.

The *second* time you tap the button, the button already has a menu, because the first tap added it; and so that menu now opens.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://nemecek.be/blog/85/how-to-show-uimenu-from-uibutton-or-uibarbuttonitem):

> If you want your UIMenu to appear immediately, you need to set the showsMenuAsPrimaryAction to true, otherwise the menu will appear after long press.

So create the menu and attach it to the button in viewDidLoad. Then set the button’s `showsMenuAsPrimaryAction` property to true.